# NodeJs : Insert data to parse table

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am inserting data to table of parse.

I have `import Parse from 'parse/node';` on the top.

And inserting the data like :

```
const game = Parse.Object.extend('Game');
const query = new Parse.Query(game);
query.set('name', 'Delta');
query.save(null, {
    success(DOD) {
        console.log('Success');
    },
    error(DOD, error) {
        console.log('Failed');
    },
});
```

It throws error :

`TypeError: query.set is not a function`.

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

This method is simply not available. See [API Parse](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Query.html)